# `bundle install` failed due to permission denied

Tags: ruby, bundler, permission-denied

I've installed bundler gem on my new server and when I try to execute `bundle install`, it failed with this error :

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/gems (Errno::EACCES)
```

My server is a Debian wheezy (7.1) with default ruby 1.9.3 package installed. I have configured `/etc/gemrc` like this : `gem: --user-install` to allow users install gems locally.

The bundler gem was installed inside my user's gems dir `~/.gem` like i want with this command : `gem install bundler` (no sudo). But bundler want install gems into `/var/lib/gems` instead my gems directory :(

I don't understand what's wrong with bundler... Why it doesn't try to install gem where I want (in my gems local dir) ?

ps: in my laptop, with archlinux and default ruby 2.0.0 package installed, I have no problems with bundler to install user's gems.

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager?

Comment: no... I tried with rbenv with same result and i've remove it.

Comment: Related: [ruby on rails - Force bundler to install gems in user’s home directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031061/force-bundler-to-install-gems-in-user-s-home-directory)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found !

I had updated my rubygem like this `gem update --system`. But only my local gems were update due to the `gem: --user-install` restriction in my `/etc/.gemrc`. When bundler works, it use the global rubygem and not mine.

To fixe this issue, I updated the global rubygems with : `sudo gem update --system --no-user-install`.

And all works fine !

Answer (score 26):

According to [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.9/bundle_install.html), a `$BUNDLE_PATH` or `$GEM_HOME` env variable can be set to make it the default writeable place.

```
export BUNDLE_PATH=~/.gems

bundle install
```

It is pretty handy if you {do not have/do not want to use} root access.

Comment: where did you find this in bundler documentation?

Answer (score 14):

`bundle install` does not use the gemrc settings. (Although [possibly that has changed](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1009) in a recent update, but the update appears to load ~/.gemrc only, not /etc/gemrc)

You can do what you want with `bundle install --path ~/.gem`

However, I would highly recommend getting rbenv or RVM working. You said that you had the "same result" with rbenv. If your gems were trying to install into `/var/lib/gems` when you had rbenv installed, then it wasn't an rbenv-installed Ruby that was running that command. Either rbenv was still using the system Ruby (which it will until you pick an rbenv installed Ruby to become the default), or you did not have rbenv running correctly.

Comment: You've right ! Bundler works fine with a rbenv well configured. My problem seams due to my `~/.profile` who is badly load when i'm log in. I'm must explicitly load it with `source ~/.profile`. I'll move rbenv into `.bashrc`. Thanks !!! ;)