# How to fix "sudo bundle install"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, root, sudo

I read a lot of questions like "[How can I fix an accidental 'sudo bundle install dir_name'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862174/how-can-i-fix-an-accidental-sudo-bundle-install-dir-name)", "[cannot recover from `sudo bundle install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078493/cannot-recover-from-sudo-bundle-install)", "[`bundle install` failed due to permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959435/bundle-install-failed-due-to-permission-denied?rq=1)" but none worked for me.

Under Debian 10.2, I ran `bundle install` as `root` by mistake. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> than 1 second after I issue it.
Now, as normal user, every time I try to use `bundle` I get:

```
bash: /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/bin/bundle: Permission denied
```

I did:

- `gem uninstall bundler` and `gem install bundler`
- `rm -r ~/.bundle/`
- `rm -r ~/.gem/`
- `bundle install --path ~/.gem` and its variants
- checked all the files under `~/gems` are owned by myself

The `permission denied` error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Bundler's documentation:

> By default, Bundler installs gems to the same location as gem install.
>
> In some cases, that location may not be writable by your Unix user. In that case, >Bundler will stage everything in a temporary directory, then ask you for your >sudo password in order to copy the gems into their system location.
>
> From your perspective, this is identical to installing the gems directly into the >system.
>
> You should never use sudo bundle install. This is because several other steps in >bundle install must be performed as the current user:
>
> Updating your Gemfile.lock
>
> Updating your vendor/cache, if necessary
>
> Checking out private git repositories using your user's SSH keys
>
> Of these three, the first two could theoretically be performed by chowning the >resulting files to $SUDO_USER. The third, however, can only be performed by >invoking the git command as the current user. Therefore, git gems are downloaded >and installed into ~/.bundle rather than $GEM_HOME or $BUNDLE_PATH.
>
> As a result, you should run bundle install as the current user, and Bundler will >ask for your password if it is needed to put the gems into their final location.

As a possible solution you can fully uninstall Ruby and its dependencies, and then install Ruby using asdf, RVM or rbenv and run Bundler again.

I use Bundler just to install gems from a gemfile. `cd` into the project with the gemfile and run `bundle install`. It must find the gemfile and install the gems automatically. I think it's bad to use Bundler inside the home directory.

I have all gems installed here:

```sh
~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems
```

Comment: I had to reinstall everything from scratch. It's just a bit rude...

Comment: Glad You got a fix of this problem!
As advice - use sudo, only if it requested, and better to check what it (e.g bundler) does and then make a decision (use sudo or not).

Comment: Of course. I was aware I cannot use `sudo` with bundler. As said it was a mistake due to "automation" after a permission denied message :)

Comment: is it safe type type in the password to the script? I did `sudo` because I didn't want to hand off that kind of info to some other program I can't trust.