# Permission Denied for bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permission-denied

I have a project in which I tried bundle install. After googling I did something like

```
export GEM_HOME=/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

If I run bundle install I am running into a problem

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/lib/gems
```

How will I solve this problem? PLease Help as it is a shared environment.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo bundle install`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Do not use `sudo` to install your gems unless they are really needed for all the users. This is a lazy practice and should be frowned upon.
`chown`ing the global gem dir is almost the same as the first option. In real life you usually won't get the root password so easily and it is a security risk for the company.

`/var/lib/gems` is not a location that your user has an access to. That is why you get an error when trying to install something on it.

To answer your question, you can use `--user-install` option. That puts them into `~/.gem/ruby/#{version}`. So the gems install for your user only.

Some other clues can be found here -> [Force bundler to install gems in user’s home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031061/force-bundler-to-install-gems-in-user-s-home-directory)

Comment: this is the best solution, and the best advice to not use `sudo` or `chown`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permission to your current User to access the gems directory using-

```
sudo chown -R user_name /var/lib/gems
```